# Removing from nested lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've got a homework assignment that has stumped me! I have to create a function goo(A L) that will remove every A in L and it has to work on nested lists also.

Here's what I've got so far

```
(defun goo(A L)
(cond ((null L) nil) ; if list is null, return nil
(T  ; else list is not null
    (cond ((atom (car L))) ;if car L is an atom
        ((cond ((equal A (car L)) (goo A (cdr L)))  ;if car L = A, call goo A cdr L
            (T (cons (car L) (goo A (cdr L)))))) ;if car L != A, 
    (T (cons (goo A (car L)) (goo A (cdr L))))))    ;else car L is not atom, call goo on car L and call goo on cdr L
))
```

This function returns True no matter what I give it.

Comment: if you found a solution that works for you, don't edit it into the question, but post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.  For the moment, I've copied it into a community wiki answer, and removed it from the question.  Feel free to post your own answer, though, and I'll remove the CW answer.

Answer (score 2):

You parens are messed up. Move the last paren around `(atom (car L))` to include the next `cond` expression. I suggest using an IDE which shows matching parens.

As for styling, if you didn't know, [`cond` can accept multiple clauses](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm). This way you don't need to have the `t` and then the `cond` again. You can also [use 'if'](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm#if) if you are only testing a single predicate and making a decision based solely on that.

Comment: Thanks feller. Moving the parens gave me an error but I tried another method using the cond multiple clauses thing and got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> *Note: this was originally posted as an edit to the question by the original asker in [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25234257/2).*

I tried another approach and it's working now.

```
(defun goo(A L)
(cond ((null L) nil)
      ((atom (car L)) (cond ((equal A (car L)) (goo A (cdr L)))
                        (T (cons (car L) (goo A (cdr L))))))
      (T (cons (goo A (car L)) (goo A (cdr L))))
))
```

> *Note 2: this should conventionally be formatted like this to show the program structure:*

```
(defun goo (a l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((atom (car l))
         (cond ((equal a (car l))
                (goo a (cdr l)))
               (t (cons (car l)
                        (goo a (cdr l))))))
        (t (cons (goo a (car l))
                 (goo a (cdr l))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to look at this a replacement into *trees* problem.  It's easy to define a function that takes a tree and replaces subtrees in it that satisfy a test.  There's a standard function [subst-if](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm) that does that, but it replaces every matching subtree with the same thing.  It will be more useful to us if we replace the element with a value computed from the subtree:

```
(defun %subst-if (new test tree)
  "Replace subtrees of TREE that satisfy TEST with the result 
of calling NEW with the subtree."
  (cond
    ;; If tree satifies the test, return (new tree).
    ((funcall test tree)
     (funcall new tree))
    ;; If tree is a cons, recurse.
    ((consp tree)
     (cons (%subst-if new test (car tree))
           (%subst-if new test (cdr tree))))
    ;; Otherwise, just return the leaf.
    (tree)))
```

With this, its easy to define the kind of function we need.  When an element X appears somewhere in a nested list structure, it means that there is a cons cell whose car is X.  We want to replace that cons cell with its cdr, but to also recurse on the cdr of the cell.  This isn't hard:

```
(defun replace* (x list &key (test 'eql))
  "Remove occurrences of X in LIST and  its sublists."
  (%subst-if
   (lambda (cons)
     "Replace elements of the form (X . more) with
      (replace* x more :test test)."
     (replace* x (cdr cons) :test test))
   (lambda (subtree)
     "Detect subtrees of the form (X . more)."
     (and (consp subtree)
          (funcall test x (car subtree))))
   list))
```

```
(replace* 'a '(1 a (2 a 3) a 4 a 5))
;=> (1 (2 3) 4 5)
```